# Unity3D - Screen Capture of particular UI elements

Tags: unity, screenshot

How can I screenshot particular UI elements?

In my case I need screen capture UI Panel with child objects like UI Text, UI Input and etc.

Please take a look at picture. Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: This may be what you are looking for http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/22954/how-to-save-a-picture-take-screenshot-from-a-camer.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;

public class ScreenshotNow : MonoBehaviour 
{
public RectTransform rectT; // Assign the UI element which you wanna capture
int width; // width of the object to capture
int height; // height of the object to capture

// Use this for initialization
void Start () 
{
    width = System.Convert.ToInt32(rectT.rect.width); 
    height = System.Convert.ToInt32(rectT.rect.height);
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () 
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) 
    {
        StartCoroutine(takeScreenShot ()); // screenshot of a particular UI Element.
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.A)) 
    {
        Application.CaptureScreenshot ("FullPageScreenShot.png");
    }

}
public IEnumerator takeScreenShot()
{
    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame (); // it must be a coroutine 

    Vector2 temp = rectT.transform.position;
    var startX = temp.x - width/2;
    var startY = temp.y - height/2;

    var tex = new Texture2D (width, height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
    tex.ReadPixels (new Rect(startX, startY, width, height), 0, 0);
    tex.Apply ();

    // Encode texture into PNG
    var bytes = tex.EncodeToPNG();
    Destroy(tex);

    File.WriteAllBytes(Application.dataPath + "ScreenShot.png", bytes);

}
}
```

Comment: It captures my Panel differently evety time when I'm changing the size of game window. So, its unstable now. And in full size windows it captures only a part of UI Panel

Comment: I just cheked it in my Unity editor with different landscape and portrait resolutions and also in maximize screen. It worked fine. have u assigned the "rectT" in the inspector

Comment: Yes, assigned. Please take a look http://imgur.com/se18het

Comment: Check the byte to sprite converter scripts. I think there might be a problem. Here is my script I made for you. Try this, let me know if the problem still exits. 
https://gist.github.com/Shubhra22/bab1052cd90b9f4b89b3

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VdJqUj7ucQU

Comment: Did you watch this screencast?

Comment: I think the image will be responsive in different screen resolution. But It can't change the resolution in run time.Have to do some works on that

Answer (score 1):

```
public class ScreenShotRect : MonoBehaviour {

    public RectTransform rectT; // Assign the UI element which you wanna capture

    private int width; // width of the object to capture
    private int height; // height of the object to capture
    private Transform rectTransformParent;  //RectTransform parent to reasign after usage
    private GameObject screenShotGO;    //Tempory GameObject to copy recttransform
                                        //RectTransform values to reasign after usage
    private Vector2 offsetMinValues;
    private Vector2 offsetMaxValues;
    private Vector3 localScaleValues;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            if (rectT != null)
            {
                if (rectT.root.GetComponent<CanvasScaler>().uiScaleMode == CanvasScaler.ScaleMode.ScaleWithScreenSize)
                {
                    if (rectT.root.GetComponent<CanvasScaler>().screenMatchMode != CanvasScaler.ScreenMatchMode.MatchWidthOrHeight || 
                        rectT.root.GetComponent<CanvasScaler>().matchWidthOrHeight != 0.5f)
                    { 
                            Debug.LogWarning("UI may not look the same due to Canvas Scaler either screenMatchMode was not set MatchWidthOrHeight or MatchWidthOrHeight is not set to 0.5f");
                    }
                    createCanvasWithRectTransform();
                }
                else if (rectT.root.GetComponent<CanvasScaler>().uiScaleMode == CanvasScaler.ScaleMode.ConstantPixelSize)
                {
                    StartCoroutine(takeScreenShot());
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.LogWarning("Canvas Scaler mode not supported.");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("Rect transform is null to capture the screenshot, hence fullscreen has been taken.");
                Application.CaptureScreenshot("FullPageScreenShot.png");
            }
        }

    }

    private void createCanvasWithRectTransform()
    {
        rectTransformParent = rectT.parent; //Assigning Parent transform to reasign after usage

        //Copying RectTransform values to reasign after switching parent
        offsetMinValues = rectT.offsetMin;
        offsetMaxValues = rectT.offsetMax;
        localScaleValues = rectT.localScale;

        //Creating secondary CANVAS with required fields
        screenShotGO = new GameObject("ScreenShotGO");
        screenShotGO.transform.parent = null;
        Canvas canvas = screenShotGO.AddComponent<Canvas>();
        canvas.renderMode = RenderMode.ScreenSpaceOverlay;
        CanvasScaler canvasScalar = screenShotGO.AddComponent<CanvasScaler>();
        canvasScalar.uiScaleMode = CanvasScaler.ScaleMode.ConstantPixelSize;
        screenShotGO.AddComponent<GraphicRaycaster>();

        rectT.SetParent(screenShotGO.transform);    //Assigning capture recttransform to temporary parent gameobject

        //Reasigning recttransform values
        rectT.offsetMin = offsetMinValues;
        rectT.offsetMax = offsetMaxValues;
        rectT.localScale = localScaleValues;

        Canvas.ForceUpdateCanvases();   // Forcing all canvas to update the UI

        StartCoroutine(takeScreenShot());   //Once everything was set ready, Capture the screenshot
    }

    private IEnumerator takeScreenShot()
    {
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame(); // it must be a coroutine 

        //Calcualtion for the width and height of the screenshot from recttransform
        width = System.Convert.ToInt32(rectT.rect.width);
        height = System.Convert.ToInt32(rectT.rect.height);

        //Calcualtion for the starting position of the recttransform to be captured
        Vector2 temp = rectT.transform.position;
        var startX = temp.x - width / 2;
        var startY = temp.y - height / 2;

        // Read the pixels from the texture
        var tex = new Texture2D(width, height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
        tex.ReadPixels(new Rect(startX, startY, width, height), 0, 0);
        tex.Apply();

        // split the process up--ReadPixels() and the GetPixels() call inside of the encoder are both pretty heavy
        yield return 0;

        var bytes = tex.EncodeToPNG();
        Destroy(tex);

        //Writing bytes to a file
        File.WriteAllBytes(Application.dataPath + "/ScreenShotRect/ScreenShot.png", bytes);

        //In case of ScaleMode was not ScaleWithScreenSize, parent will not be assigned then no need to revert the changes
        if (rectTransformParent != null)
        {
            //Reasigning gameobject to its original parent group
            rectT.SetParent(rectTransformParent);

            //Reasigning recttransform values
            rectT.offsetMin = offsetMinValues;
            rectT.offsetMax = offsetMaxValues;
            rectT.localScale = localScaleValues;

            //Destorying temporary created gameobject after usage
            Destroy(screenShotGO);
        }

        Debug.Log("Picture taken");
    }
}
```

Note: UI may not look the same when Canvas Scaler either screenMatchMode was not set MatchWidthOrHeight or MatchWidthOrHeight is not set to 0.5f

This code is modified based on [Shuvro Sarkar](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/51157/shuvro-sarkar)'s answer

Answer (score 0):

In my runs, I discovered the solution to the size of the window and only part of the panel problem was solved by going to the Canvas Scaler and changing UI Scale mode to costant pixel.

Answer (score 0):

This is the modified answer for `scaleWithScreenSize` option on **CanvasScaler**,

```
    if(sourceRect.root.GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.CanvasScaler>().uiScaleMode == UnityEngine.UI.CanvasScaler.ScaleMode.ScaleWithScreenSize)
    {
        UnityEngine.UI.CanvasScaler scaler = sourceRect.root.GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.CanvasScaler>();
        if (scaler.matchWidthOrHeight == 0)
        {
            height = System.Convert.ToInt32((float)Screen.width  / (float)width * height);
            width = Screen.width;
        }
        else // scaler.matchWidthOrHeight == 1
        {
            width = System.Convert.ToInt32((float)Screen.height / (float)height * width);
            height = Screen.height;
        }
    }
```

Just a quick fix for the `matchWidthOrHeight` on 0 and 1, If anyone have some idea about the value between, please let me know :)

(Add code below `Vector2 temp = rectT.transform.position;` from [Shuvro Sarkar](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/51157/shuvro-sarkar)'s answer)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish this even with CanvasScaler set to scaleWithScreenSize and matchWidthOrHeight set to arbitrary value, using the RectTransformUtility api:

```
    Rect rect = RectTransformUtility.PixelAdjustRect(rectT, canvas);

    int textWidth = System.Convert.ToInt32(rect.width); // width of the object to capture
    int textHeight = System.Convert.ToInt32(rect.height); // height of the object to capture

    var startX = System.Convert.ToInt32(rect.x) + Screen.width / 2; // offset X
    var startY = System.Convert.ToInt32(rect.y) + Screen.height / 2; // offset Y

    var tex = new Texture2D(textWidth, textHeight, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
    tex.ReadPixels(new Rect(startX, startY, textWidth, textHeight), 0, 0);
    tex.Apply();
```

Answer (score 0):

Some people may want go for something simple using the built-in capture, and into texture, for our case texture does not need to be written to file, you can whatever with the texture.

```
private IEnumerator takeScreenShot()
{
    // GameObject to hide while capturing
    ControlsGO.SetActive(false);

    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

    Texture2D texture;
    if (!ControlsGO.activeSelf)
    {
        texture = ScreenCapture.CaptureScreenshotAsTexture();
        finishedMainRoutine = true;
        ControlsGO.SetActive(true);

        var bytes = texture.EncodeToPNG();

        File.WriteAllBytes(Application.dataPath + "ScreenShot.png", bytes);
        Debug.Log("Done");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will do exactly this.

```cs
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
 
public class TakeScreenshotAndSave : MonoBehaviour
{
    //Object To Screenshot
    [SerializeField] private RectTransform _objToScreenshot;
 
    //Assign the button to take screenshot on clicking
    [SerializeField] private Button _takeScreenshotButton;
 
    void Start()
    {
        _takeScreenshotButton.onClick.AddListener(OnClickTakeScreenshotAndSaveButton);
    }
 
    private void OnClickTakeScreenshotAndSaveButton()
    {
        StartCoroutine(TakeSnapShotAndSave());
    }
 
    //Using a Coroutine instead of normal method
    public IEnumerator TakeSnapShotAndSave()
    {
        //Code will throw error at runtime if this is removed
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
 
        //Get the corners of RectTransform rect and store it in a array vector
        Vector3[] corners = new Vector3[4];
        _objToScreenshot.GetWorldCorners(corners);
 
        //Remove 100 and you will get error
        int width = ((int)corners[3].x - (int)corners[0].x) - 100;
        int height = (int)corners[1].y - (int)corners[0].y;
        var startX = corners[0].x;
        var startY = corners[0].y;
 
        //Make a temporary texture and read pixels from it
        Texture2D ss = new Texture2D(width, height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
        ss.ReadPixels(new Rect(startX, startY, width, height), 0, 0);
        ss.Apply();
 
        Debug.Log("Start X : " + startX + " Start Y : " + startY);
        Debug.Log("Screen Width : " + Screen.width + " Screen Height : " + Screen.height);
        Debug.Log("Texture Width : " + width + " Texture Height : " + height);
 
        //Save the screenshot to disk
        byte[] byteArray = ss.EncodeToPNG();
        string savePath = Application.persistentDataPath + "/ScreenshotSave.png";
        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(savePath, byteArray);
        Debug.Log("Screenshot Path : " + savePath);
 
        // Destroy texture to avoid memory leaks
        Destroy(ss);
    }
}
```

Comment: You could improve you answer by including a brief explanation or introduction, and/or providing a simple step-by-step use guide.